# Attack on a Linux file server | What is the damage of this file contents?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, c#, nano

#### TCP Networking

This file was uploaded using a loophole in a file uploading network program I was writing. The ability to access the server itself was too simple and the techniques I used resulted in someone being able to decompile the code and rewrite the upload method used.

The client program uses sockets to connect to the server program through .NET's TcpClient to then download the contents of this file, then display the text contents of the file into a WPF ListBox.

#### The Resulting HTTP Header

[Screenshot of the file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5lB0.png)

#### Question

Is this serious? Unfortunately someone had downloaded this file with the compromised data.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to say based on what you have provided.  Also, that is not a "nano" file, its likely some kind of web file (but not an html file) as indicated by the header part.

Comment: There were some edits made to the post to explain further how the data was acquired then used by the client through the server.

Comment: We still font know the file payload so we still can't answer.

Comment: The only file uploaded was the one with the HTTP header and long line of repeated characters. As for a payload, I am not exactly sure what it was, if any. 

The program simply reported the process of uploading two files in the console log (that is now lost--it was not recorded, a fault that is mine), and each consecutive file uploaded archives the previous one upon success.

Comment: If what you say is true - which I'm skeptical of - the output is harmless. I suspect the long line of repeated characters were not repeated characters, rather a padded payload or more likely ASCII with the ^@ symbol represents an ASCII character with a decimal value > 127

Comment: The encoding is set to be ASCII, and the upload process writes everything sent over the network to a text file, archiving the previous version in the process. It does not truncate the data and uploads empty bytes seen as \0\0\0\0\0-etc. in Visual Studio. Maybe there is still a vulnerability. I can post some of the source code of the project if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long string of ASCII characters after the HTML header was the result of byte values not being cut off from the network transmission of data. Looking at the data in a Windows IDE shows that the value is /0/0/0... etc. being written to the remote server.

Due to how the file was handled by the server program, it is unlikely that it caused any problem.